# Change default indentation width in Xcode 8

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I know how to change code indentation in a single project and found a solution for changing default indentation in Xcode 4.5.

But in Xcode 8 there is no such item in "Preferences" as  "Indent width".

So how can I make my Xcode create all the new projects with indentation of 2 spaces intead of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **Xcode** menu, go to **Preferences** (or <kbd>command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>) then **Text Editing** > **Indentation** :

[image: Text Editing Indentation]

Answer (score 4):

To get to preferences press CMD+,

Then go to text editor, then indentation and the options are there.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to change from command line.

```sh
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextIndentWidth -int 3
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTTextIndentTabWidth -int 3
```

*Note*: You may need to reopen project.